# How can I play Galactic Adventures in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: technical-issues, ubuntu, spore, spore-galactic-adventures

I have installed Spore and Galactic Adventures in Ubuntu 12.04 using wine-1.4, but when I try to launch Galactic Adventures, the normal game launches. Is there any way to get it to launch with the patch?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about running Spore and Spore GA under wine, but under their normal host OS, to play GA, you have to launch GA from its own installed shortcut and you need to have the GA disk. If you don't, it will run normal Spore. From your description, it sounds like either a) the launcher you are using is for normal spore, not the GA launcher, or b) its DRM isn't seeing the GA disk, so it is just going running normal Spore.

That was one advantage to installing GA--- it "cracked" normal Spore so the Spore disk was no longer needed at start up to play the normal Spore game. Useful when you wanted to travel but not worry about losing your GA disk.